# Table of Contents not being updated in Rmarkdown pdf creation

Tags: pdf, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, tableofcontents

The TOC of my pdf created from Knit.pdf in Rstudio for some reason is not being updated. It is being created but with some past information (stopped in pag 68 and I´m already on page 99).

Could be something related to cached info?

Below the YAML preamble I´m using and also checked the "include table of contents" options under Knitr Edit R markdown configuration. By the YAML below, also tried to use toc:true below pdf_document and did not work.

```
title: "My book"
author: "MyName"
date: "Mydate"
documentclass: book
fontsize: 10pt
classoption: 
        b5paper
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
   - \usepackage{longtable}
   - \usepackage{sidenotes}
   - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{MyContent}
   - \renewcommand{\chaptername}{MyChapter}
 geometry:
  - tmargin=2cm
  - bmargin=2cm
  - lmargin=2cm
  - rmargin=2cm
toc: yes
output: 
  pdf_document:
     fig_caption: yes
     highlight: zenburn
     latex_engine: xelatex
     number_sections: yes
     pandoc_args: --chapters
     toc: yes
     toc_depth: 3
```

Comment: If there is a file `filename.toc` in your working directory, please try to delete it and compile again.

Comment: @ user2706569: Done. It really existed a .toc file but even after deleted Table is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have anything to do with toc being called twice, once just before output and then again under pdf document?

Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Duplicate map key: 'toc'
Calls:  ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 ->  -> .Call
Execution halted

Comment: @Chaitnaya. Not it is not...actually I had already realized that and removed the first one. Following @ user2706569 I tried to find any file in working directory that could be related and remove 2 or 3 strange input.something file....now seems it is working, although I dont know precisely what was happening. Tks!!